# Does Laravel has Rails' before_filters to bind variables into controller methods?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I'm extremely newbie on Ruby on Rails. Started learning both Ruby and Ruby on Rails just few hours ago and trying to adapt it's DRY principles into my own Laravel codes.

This is how my RoR looks like:

```
class WeddingController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :get_wedding

    def get_wedding
        /*
           If Wedding.find(2) returns false, redirect homepage
           Else, bind @wedding into all methods for use
        */
    end

    def edit
        @wedding //this method has access to @wedding, which contains Wedding.find(2) data.
    end

    def update
        //Same as above method
    end

    def destroy
        //Same as above method, can do things like @wedding.destroy
    end
end
```

This is how my Laravel looks like

```
class Wedding_Controller extends Base_Controller {

public function edit($id)
{
    if(Wedding::find($id) === false)
       return Redirect::to('/);

    //Edit code
}

public function update($id)
{
    if(Wedding::find($id) === false)
       return Redirect::to('/);

    //Update code
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    if(Wedding::find($id) === false)
       return Redirect::to('/);

    //Destroy code
}
}
```

1. How can I DRY `if(Wedding::find($id) === false)` checks to be like my RoR code?
2. If `Wedding::find($id) returns actual Wedding data`, how can I inject it as `$wedding variable` in all specified methods? (Not looking for anything using class scope, if possible.)

Thanks alot!

Ps. For people who doesn't understand my RoR script; basically it does this.

```
Before any method call on this controller, execute get_wedding method first. 
If get_wedding can't find the wedding in database, let it redirect to homepage.
If get_wedding finds the wedding in database, inject returned value as @wedding variable to all methods so they can make use of it. (e.g destroy method calling @wedding.destroy() directly.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, before filters can manipulate data being passed to the route. For example:

```
Route::filter('wedding', function($route, $request) {
    $id = $route->getParameter('id');
    $wedding = Wedding::findOrFail($id); // if no wedding is found, it returns a 404 here
    // Here is where we hit a small road block. You can call
    $route->setParameters(array($wedding));
    // But you just erased any other parameters the route was accepting.
    // So then you start getting *all* the parameters
    $params = $route->getParameters();
    // Then you try to merge your data in somehow, then you set it back, etc.
});
```

There is an easier way!

From the structure of your controller, I am assuming it is a resource controller. Take the following example:

```
Route::model('wedding, 'Wedding'); // varname, model name
Route::resource('wedding', 'WeddingController'); // The first param here matches the first param above.

class WeddingController extends BaseController {
    ...
    public function show(Wedding $wedding) {
        return View::make('wedding')->with('wedding', $wedding);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is called Route-Model binding. For more info, see http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding

*EDIT*

Let me expand on this example, say one day you need to have a url like `/wedding/cahill-manley` instead of `/wedding/123`, You could delete the `Route::model` line, and in its place add:

```
Route::bind('wedding', function($value) {
    return Wedding::where('slug', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

And then things keep on working.

Comment: I'm not really an expert on Laravel yet, so I don't know if my controller is a resource controller. I'll hit google up to see what resource controller is. Not familiar with terms.

Comment: Its a resource controller if you use the `Route::resource` function. See http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: No, all my method calls are direct calls. Like; Route::get('something/{id}', 'SomethingController@show');

Comment: Then you would change `{id}` to `{wedding}` and the route binding would work. It is based on the variable name.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow after having a fresh sleep, but still; RoR's example looks much more easier and maintainable than this. Since Laravel is basically a Rails clone, there is no other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the wedding filter and apply it to the Wedding Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('wedding');
}
```

I don't know how you can replicate @wedding.destroy, but if you want to inject a variable all over the place, you can use `View::share()` in `App:before()` located at **app/filters.php**.

```
App::before(function($request)
{

    $check_wedding = Wedding::where('...');
    if($check_wedding)
    {
        View::share('wedding', $check_wedding);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

});
```

Comment: View::share only shares variable across view files. I need to do it in controller.

Comment: Yes, I apologize Mr. Imaqtpie. If I change View::share to Config::set then Config::get('wedding') will be available in all controllers. I hope someone show how to have $wedding available everywhere as I'm interested too.